# AVD Manager runs but android.bat does not

Tags: android-emulator, command-line, android-sdk

I can create virtual devices using AVD manager. I can run the emulator and create AVDs. But i cannot do the same using "android.bat".

I get the following error-

```
ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
```

I have tried every other suggestion that i have come across, including tweaks in the "find_java.bat" and "android.bat".
I am perplexed by the fact that AVD manager works but the batch file does not.

Could this be a bug? How do i fix this?

Operating System: Windows 7 (64-bit)
Android: API 10
Java: 1.6.0_19 (both jdk and jre)